# ZPL Field reverse not working

Tags: zpl-ii

I've got 3 text fields, and i've set a graphic box that covers the whole area. For each text field i've put the ^FR in front. I've also specified LRN at the top of my ZPL.

For some reason though only the top text field goes white font on black. The other two text fields stay in black so aren't visible, despite appearing to be set up the same and having the FR field specified. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Show us your code so that we can attempt to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 7):

You may be doing too much, trying to use both ^LR and ^FR.

Here's an example that seems to work, using just ^FR (view online [here](http://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=6&zpl=%5EXA%0A%5EFO100%2C100%5EGB200%2C120%2C120%5EFS%0A%5EFO110%2C110%5EFR%5EAC%5EFDThe%20first%20line%5EFS%0A%5EFO110%2C150%5EFR%5EAC%5EFDThe%20second%20line%5EFS%0A%5EFO110%2C190%5EFR%5EAC%5EFDThe%20third%20line%5EFS%0A%5EXZ)):

```
^XA
^FO100,100^GB200,120,120^FS
^FO110,110^FR^AC^FDThe first line^FS
^FO110,150^FR^AC^FDThe second line^FS
^FO110,190^FR^AC^FDThe third line^FS
^XZ
```

And here's an example that just uses ^LR (view online [here](http://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=6&zpl=%5EXA%0A%5ELRY%0A%5EFO100%2C100%5EGB200%2C120%2C120%5EFS%0A%5EFO110%2C110%5EAC%5EFDThe%20first%20line%5EFS%0A%5EFO110%2C150%5EAC%5EFDThe%20second%20line%5EFS%0A%5EFO110%2C190%5EAC%5EFDThe%20third%20line%5EFS%0A%5EXZ)):

```
^XA
^LRY
^FO100,100^GB200,120,120^FS
^FO110,110^AC^FDThe first line^FS
^FO110,150^AC^FDThe second line^FS
^FO110,190^AC^FDThe third line^FS
^XZ
```